# How to compile Hadoop for 64-bit Linux machine?

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, compilation, maven-2

I've downloaded the latest stable binaries of Hadoop (2.2.0). Just as I initialized HDFS, I got this warning:

> WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for
>   your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

I understand that I can fix this by compiling from source so I downloaded the source package from Hadoop. I know the basic process of compiling but got confused after reading the README. A quick google showed that I have to use maven for this, which is a tool to build java based projects.

So my question is, how do I use maven to compile Hadoop from source? Should I go into each directory and compile each of the modules? A step by step guide would be very helpful, and explanations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Once you extract the source you would find a super pom in location like below.
\hadoop-2.2.0-src.tar\hadoop-2.2.0-src\hadoop-2.2.0-src\pom.xml
This would build all the modules.
You can build using command:  mvn clean install

You should notice logs like below.

```
            [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            [INFO] Reactor Build Order:
            [INFO]
            [INFO] Apache Hadoop Main
            [INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM
            [INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations
            [INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM
            [INFO] Apache Hadoop Assemblies
            [INFO] Apache Hadoop Maven Plugins
            [INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth
            [INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth Examples
            [INFO] Apache Hadoop Common
            [INFO] Apache Hadoop NFS
            [INFO] Apache Hadoop Common Project
            [INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS
            [INFO] Apache Hadoop HttpFS
            [INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS BookKeeper Journal
            [INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS-NFS
            [INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Project
            [INFO] hadoop-yarn
            [INFO] hadoop-yarn-api
            [INFO] hadoop-yarn-common
            [INFO] hadoop-yarn-server
            [INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-common
            [INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager
            [INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy
            [INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager
            [INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-tests
            [INFO] hadoop-yarn-client
            [INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications
            [INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell
            [INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client
            [INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-core
            [INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher
            [INFO] hadoop-yarn-site
            [INFO] hadoop-yarn-project
            [INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-common
            [INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle
            [INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-app
            [INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs
            [INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient
            [INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins
            [INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Examples
            [INFO] hadoop-mapreduce
```

and more......

However this is a long trip approach if you just want to use Hadoop.
You should be able to use the existing libraries.
Could be some configuration issue.

Other option is Cloudera. I have installed this on RedHat Linux.

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Quick-Start/cdh4qs_topic_3.html

Good luck.

Comment: I was thinking I needed the natively-built Hadoop to avoid compatibility issues and maybe gain a small boost in performance. Does it actually matter if I use the Hadoop binaries instead? Will it be slower or anything? I'm also wondering why they use 32-bit by default.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Apache Bigtop](https://bigtop.apache.org/) to build Hadoop.

It's IMHO the most convenient way of compiling Hadoop yourself, as long as you only need the "mainsteam" components and stable versions.

Comment: Can you share the SVN location

Comment: Check the homepage for the current location.